# Seaborn barplot label bars with 3rd variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am fairly new to Python visualization. I have data with 3 variables; month, frequency and word. I am trying to see which word appeared most in a month.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

test = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['2019-01','2019-02','2019-03','2019-04','2019-05'],
             'freq':[3,5,22,6,3],
             'word':['hello','world','seaborn','seaborn','python']})


sns.barplot(x = 'month', y = 'freq', data = test)
```

So far, I have month on the x-axis, freq on the y-axis. But, I want to label bars with the words that appear in those months. For example "hello" should appear on Jan-2019 bar.

[image: Test]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [plt.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) to put the labels in the desired locations.

The `ha` and `va` keywords take care of proper (horizontal/vertical) alignment.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['2019-01','2019-02','2019-03','2019-04','2019-05'],
             'freq':[3,5,22,6,3],
             'word':['hello','world','seaborn','seaborn','python']})

for i in test.index:
    word = test.loc[i, "word"]
    y = test.loc[i, "freq"]
    plt.annotate(word, (i, y), ha="center", va="bottom")

sns.barplot(x = 'month', y = 'freq', data = test);
```

[image: Barplot with labels]

Comment: Thank you! I tried using the bar_labels function in Matplotlib but can't get it to work. How do I make the text smaller?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you can do in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

test = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['2019-01','2019-02','2019-03','2019-04','2019-05'],
         'freq':[3,5,22,6,3],
         'word':['hello','world','seaborn','exp','python']})

ax = sns.barplot(x = 'month', y = 'freq', data = test)

for bar, label in zip(ax.patches, test['word']):
    x = bar.get_x()
    width = bar.get_width()
    height = bar.get_height()
    ax.text(x+width/2., height + 0.2, label, ha="center")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what is required. I want labels on top of bars because in the larger dataset, some words will repeat in multiple months.

Comment: @UmerNaeem check the answer now